# Bigquery/Standard Sql: Remove top 10% and bottom 10% of the cohort

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is my query, I wish to remove top 10% and bottom 10% of the cohort before I average different KPI say sales (this will be after filtering via case). Is there any way to do this via query? I don't mean top 10 percentile, but top 10% of the value (= the difference would be say at the bottom alot of values are 0 for sales and if I remove based on bottom 10 percentile I am removing more than 10 percent of cohort)...

```
SELECT
  m.country,
  d.month,
  AVG(CASE WHEN d.active_dates > 10 THEN d.sales ELSE NULL END) as avg_sales,
  AVG(CASE WHEN d.active_dates > 10 THEN d.activity ELSE NULL END) as avg_act
t2.occ_stly ELSE NULL END) as stly_occ,
ROM metadata m
JOIN data d ON m.id = d.id
where m.id > 10000
GROUP BY country, month
```